# Code about a particle bouncing on a curved surface

Tags: c++, bgi

I'm supposed to write a code that simulates an inelastic particle bouncing within a wall and a semicircle (radius 30, center @ (50,0). The particle loses 3% of its original velocity every time it hits a wall and/or the semicircle.

I'm also using graphics.h library

I have made most of the program already, but the particle does not properly bounce on the semicircle.

I used the reflection matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
 cos 2\theta & sin2\theta \ 
 sin2 \theta & -cos2\theta
\end{bmatrix}

here is the this snippet of the code containing the conditions when the particle hits the semicircle:

```
 //initial conditions
   x = 0;
    y = 100;
    Vx = 15.0;
    Vy = 0.0;
    double  dt = 0.0001; //initial time step and increment

  for(double t = 0; t < 50; t += dt)
  {
      Vy = Vy + grav*dt;

      //Conditions when the particle hits a wall or the floor and retaining only 97% of its speed
      if (y<0.0)
      {
          Vy = -Vy + grav*dt;
      }

 if(x >100.0 || x < 0.0)
{
    Vx = -Vx;
}

//condition when the particle hits the semicircle
//semicircle equation: y = sqrt(30^2 - (x-50)^2)
if(y < sqrt((30*30)-((x-50)*(x-50))) )
{
    Vxnew = ((Vx)*(cos(2.0*theta)) + (Vy*(sin(2.0*theta))));
    Vy = (Vy*(cos(2.0*theta)) - ((Vx)*(sin(2.0*theta))));

    Vx = Vxnew;
}

x = x + Vx*dt;
y = y + Vy*dt;

putpixel(conx(x), cony(y), 15);
  }
```

I'm not sure if this reflection matrix applies on curved surfaces and I should use something else or my implementation is wrong.

For the losing the velocity part, I can probably just multiply the new x and y velocities by 0.97.

For context, this function that I made converts the calculated value in the loop to pixel values

```
    //convert to pixel value (scale of 6)
    double conx(double x)
  {
      return x * (600/100) + 50;
    }

    double cony(double y)
  {
      return -y * (600/100) + 650;
  }
```

[image: Here is the sample output]

Comment: Show the velocity vector before it bounces and after it bounces and explain why you think it is wrong.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, you need to take the tangent to the semicircle at point of contact as the reflecting surface. Calculus mate!